# Input fields validation in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I wrote a function to validate one input field in a form by jquery . but there are two additional text fields in my form . I am not sure a way to add tow additional rules to them . This is what i have tried so far .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.validator.addMethod("url_validation", function (value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^(([http|https|HTTPS|HTTP]+:\/\/))?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/i.test(value);
}, "error");

$('#myform').validate({
    /** this section is working */
    rules: {
        text_name: {
            required: true,
            url_validation: true,
            maxlength: 2000
        }
    },
    messages: {
        text_name: {
            required: "Please specify a URL",
            url_validation: "The domain you have entered is not a valid domain or sub domain name. Please try again.",
            maxlength: "You have exceeded the maximum length"
        }
    }
    /**********************************************************/
    /*this is where i tried to add other rules to two of my other textboxes*/
    rules: {
        text_name2: {
            required: true,
            url_validation: true,
            maxlength: 2000
        }
    },
    messages: {
        text_name2: {
            required: "Please specify a URL",
            url_validation: "The domain you have entered is not a valid domain or sub domain name. Please try again.",
            maxlength: "You have exceeded the maximum length"
        }
    }
    /*above thing is not working*/

});
```

In my HTML there are other two text boxes i need to validate . how to perform this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validate plugin takes an options object with `rules` and `messages` as a parameter. Fill them up, but don't double specify the `rules` and `messages` objects.

It should be:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        text_name: {
           ...
        },
        text_name2: {
           ...
        }
    },
    messages: {
        text_name: {
           ...
        },
        text_name2: {
           ...
        }
    }
});
```